# Как забиндить элемент текущей строки DataGrid в ComboBox

Tags: wpf, .net, binding, c#

У меня есть `dataGrid` с `ItemSourse={Binding}`, и у меня есть `DataContext` в моем `Window` классе, который я устанавливаю из кода прежде чем открыть окно, и все работает отлично. Но, мне пришлось заменить ячейки одной из колонок на `ComboBox`, я сделал это так:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

//create the data template
DataTemplate cellLayout = new DataTemplate();
cellLayout.DataType = typeof(DataGridTemplateColumn);

//set up the ComboBox
OrderedDictionary dictionary = DriverService.GetDriversDictionary();
FrameworkElementFactory cbFactory = 
    new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
cbFactory.Name = "myComboFactory";
cbFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, dictionary);
cbFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, "Key");
cbFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "Value");

Binding bind = new Binding("/driverId");
bind.Converter = new DriverIdConverter();
bind.ConverterParameter = dictionary;
bind.Source = DataContext;
bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

cbFactory.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, bind);

//set the visual tree of the data template
cellLayout.VisualTree = cbFactory;

//set the item template to be our shiny new data template
column.CellTemplate = cellLayout;
column.CellEditingTemplate = cellLayout;

dataGrid.Columns[index] = column;
```

И вот что получается, `Binding("/driverId")` всегда возвращает первый элемент `ItemSourse`, но ведь `/` это путь к текущему элементы. Так в что же я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А неправильно было то, что контекст указывать не надо было, он брался из родительского контейнера. И явно пришлось указать путь, из конструктора что-то не работал. Вот правильный код:

```
var bind = new Binding("driverId")
                   {
                       Path = new PropertyPath("driverId"),
                       Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
                   };
```

Comment: Ну если уж использовать wpf, то большую часть этого когда можно перенести в xaml (с) ворчун :)